# Forcing Polymer expression re-evaluation on filter change

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I am trying to add a filter which return value depends on some private static variable value of my component. Is there a way to re-evaluate expressions using this filter on change of this variable?

For example:

```
{{ someVariable | myFilter }}
```

where `myFilter` depends on a value of some private variable. Right now it evaluates only once.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass both properties to the filter, the property you want to show and the property you want to monitor for changing, and in your custom filter you show the first only if the second has changed.

```
<body>
  <template is="auto-binding">

  <my-component count={{count}} status={{status}}></my-component>

  <h1>And here I'm outside...</h1>

  <div>Changing only if status is on: {{ {count: count, status: status} | statusIsOn }}</div>



  </template>

  <script>
    var template = document.querySelector('template[is="auto-binding"]');
    template.count=0;
    template.status =0;
    template.statusIsOn = function(value) {
      if (value.status >0)
        return value.count;
      return 0;
    };
</script>
```

A plunker showing this case here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YGCfKErYZgFyr2KRJnVv?p=preview

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't have access to this variable from outside of component.

Comment: If it's a private variable, and you cannot make it visible, then you have a problem... Could you modify the component, add new variables or functions?

Comment: This would be quite stupid from the point of the component I am building.

Comment: Private variables are that, private... Accessing to private variables from outside the component would make them public. So if you cannot modify the component, I don' see how could you do what you want.

Comment: The filter that you're using is declared inside the component? You say it evaluates only once, so it works at least once. How does it access to the component private variable?